# Application in HTTP & HTTPS. But forms on HTTPs

Tags: forms, http, https

I have a requirement wherein the application must be on both **http** and **https**. While the end user must be able to traverse the application in http, all forms should transition to https post submission.

Any advice as to how this can be achieved given that the application is deployed on **Tomcat** cluster and has a **Apache HTTP Server as a load balancer** distributing the load in a cluster.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of HTTPS; an attacker can intercept the HTTP page and change the POST URL.

Comment: As I said the forms will always be on HTTPS so they cannot be intercepted

Comment: Wrong.  You're only telling it to submit to HTTPS through an HTTP connection.  Attackers can modify that initial (GET) response and make it submit elsewhere.

Comment: So what is the best way to achieve this? I have seen many e-commerce sites which allow the customers to browse the content on http but switch to https when the user has to login on checkout. How can this be achieved in a J2ee application?

Is it that these are done thru the rewrite rules on the HTTP Server. If that is the case is the same ear deployed on both http and https or are they deployed on 2 different containers - one with http and another with https configured?

Comment: You should just use HTTPS everywhere; it's simpler and has fewer risks.

Comment: You are right but the problem is I want to avoid unnecessary performance overhead with https on all other pages. This would make slower page  serves

Comment: That is generally not true.